# Linux mv command moved data to an unknown location?

Tags: linux, unix, mv

I accidentally executed this command in SSH:

```
mv /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/*
```

Now all the data in the magento dir is gone. Does anyone know where it moved to?

Thanks!

Comment: To automagically determine in which directory your data went and if you're using Bash, do this: `a=( /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/* ); echo "${a[${#a[@]}-1]}"`. If not in Bash, this should work: `printf '%s\n' /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/* | tail -1`. Otherwise, it's very likely in the last directory, alphanumericallywise. Done.

Answer (score 20):

If the alphabetically last entry in this directory is a directory itself, they are there.

Suppose you have the files `a`, `b` and `c` and the directory `d`. In this case,

```
mv /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/*
```

expands to

```
mv /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/a /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/b /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/c /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/d
```

which is a command to move everything to `d`. Look there if there is anything.

If `d` wasn't a directory, `mv` should have complained about that.

Comment: +1 : look underneath subdirs in the /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/magento/* dir. Hint: the subdir *still* is in in the magento dir, so it should be easy as almost everything else should now be underneath it, hence there should only be one dir left (not counting those starting with a '.'). Enter that subdir, and "mv * ..". This *could* move things that were previously rightly underneath that directory, however, so you'll have to put them back. + any file that had the same name as a file of magento/* will have benn overwritten (if your "mv" is not aliased to "mv -i")

Comment: neat trick with `mv *`:  `mkdir zzz; mv *` which will move all the contents of the current directory into the directory zzz.  Just make sure you don't have any files that sort lexagraphically after zzz.

Answer (score 2):

To extend the reply of glglgl:

The command line wildcard expansion in Unix-like operating systems is performed by the shell. In most cases with Linux it would be `bash`. Its man page explicitly states that the wildcard expansion will be alphabetically sorted. The same should be valid for most of Bourne-compatible shells.

Comment: Probably not only most, but all. Otherwise there is a lack of compatibility.